# calling two jQuery function, onChange

Tags: jquery

Hi I am calling remotefunction in onChange event. i want when user select from parent dropdown, child dropdown belong to parent id will display but the default child block will be hidden. how do i call two function in onchange event.

my code:

```
<g:select optionKey="id" from="${commonList}" class="fullBorderBox"  value="${value?."${propertyName}"?."${commonPropertyName}"?.id}" name="${commonPropertyName}.id" noSelection="${['null': message(code: 'common.list.select')]}"  onchange="${remoteFunction(
                      controller: 'middlewareData',
                      action: 'populateVersion',
                      params: "'typeId=' + this.value + '&&lookUpProperty=' + '${commonPropertyName}'",
                      update: "populateSWVersion${dataindex}"
                      )};  $("#versionBlock${dataindex}").hide();"/>


<span id="versionBlock${dataindex}">
                test="${value?."${propertyName}"?."${commonPropertyName}"?.id}">
                    <g:select optionKey="id" from="${propertyList}" class="fullBorderBox" name="dummyVal" value="${value?."${propertyName}"?.id}" noSelection="${['null': message(code: 'common.list.select')]}" onclick="populateVersionList(null);" />

            </span>
            %{---pass an dynami id to populate version block pick list----}%
            <span id="populateSWVersion${dataindex}"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to write all JS handler in the html. You could move the call back event to a function in JS. Then do whatever logic you want.

```
${remoteFunction(
                      controller: 'middlewareData',
                      action: 'populateVersion',
                      params: "'typeId=' + this.value + '&&lookUpProperty=' + '${commonPropertyName}'",
                      update: "populateSWVersion${dataindex}"
                      )};  $("#versionBlock${dataindex}").hide();
```

Move this code to a JS function. From this callback you can call as much as other function you want.

```
    // make your server call
    function getData(){
    $.ajax({
     //....
     });
    }
```

Then simply wire this function to the on change event,

`onchange="getData()"`